# Failed to define class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in Module "deployment.examplapp.war"

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, wildfly

I am developing one web app using Hibernate 5.3.6, Oracle DB 12c and Wildfly 12.0.0 server. 
I could test hibernate connection calling method from test main method but when trying to deploy in wildly getting the following exception.
I kept ojdbc7 jar in **web-inf/lib** folder

```
WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver in Module "deployment.WebSocketExample.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver (Module "deployment.WebSocketExample.war" from Service Module Loader): java/sql/Driver
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:836)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:519)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:836)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:519)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ds.processors.DriverProcessor.deploy(DriverProcessor.java:63)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1714)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1693)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1540)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Make sure your web-inf/lib folder is in classpath

Comment: Nope. Needs to be installed as a module. http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/installing_oracle_jdbc_driver_on **Do not bundle  in WEB-INF/lib**

Comment: Wildfly couldn't find driver jar in your war file as well as in the modules. Either include driver jar in your war file or add it to wildfly static modules as @AlanHay mentioned.